# Magento 2 install hangs with no errors or information

Tags: php, iis-7, magento

I am trying to install Magento 2.3 on a windows server (IIS with PHP installed - No XAMP), but the installation seems to hang.

- The wizard progress shows the following: (And has been for hours)

> Starting Magento installation: File permissions check...
>
> Required extensions check...
>
> Enabling Maintenance Mode...
>
> Installing deployment configuration...
>
> Installing database schema: Schema creation/updates:

- Data and tables do get created in the specified DB. DB has 184 tables in it...
- I have no PHP errors reported in my PHP Log file.
- The Magento Installation mentions an "install.log" file that is mean to be written to the PHP temp folder. Ref: [Magento Install Doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/web/install-web_6-install.html) . However, I **do not** see this log file in the PHP temp folder (I have confirmed the location in PHP settings).
- I did, however, find an "install.log" file in the Magento \var\log folder. This file shows only the exact info that is displayed in the wizard. (As above)

\var\log\install.log ->

```
<span class="text-info">Starting Magento installation:</span><br><span class="text-info">File permissions check...</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 1 / 757]</span><br><span class="text-info">Required extensions check...</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 2 / 757]</span><br><span class="text-info">Enabling Maintenance Mode...</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 3 / 757]</span><br><span class="text-info">Installing deployment configuration...</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 4 / 757]</span><br><span class="text-info">Installing database schema:</span><br><span class="text-info">Schema creation/updates:</span><br>
```

Progress bar also stuck at 0%.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the tables contain data?  Is there a firewall on or between the magento and the database server.  Any info on the DB?  Perhaps you don't have permission to write to the PHP temp folder?

Comment: MySQL is local to IIS / PHP. (So no firewall issues)
There does not appear to be any data.
I have not checked that the magento install can write to the php_temp folder, but I did get a php error on a previous run when env.php was not writable. No errors now tho...

Comment: Have the tables been created by the current installation?  Anything in the mySQL logs?  What is "php_temp" ?  According to the installation manual you should check sys_temp_dir (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/web/install-web_6-install.html)

Comment: Yes, the setup wizard creates the tables....

I set php temp variable to windows\temp . This is also where the php log gets written to.

Comment: But the install doesn't use the "php temp variable". Run the checks as the guide says.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille , your link above, is exactly the link I posted in my initial question. There is no log written to the php_temp folder. I have also confirmed the php temp folder resolves to c:\windows\temp when calling the php function: sys_get_temp_dir ( void )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it working by basically disabling any and all limits on my application pool for this site in IIS. Even then, I had to try multiple times between hangs. Luckily, this time it continued off where it last hung...

Must be IIS that the magento setup has trouble with.